# Using ExtJS in TypeScript

Tags: extjs, typescript

Today I started with TypeScript after reading the [blogpost](http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/using-extjs-with-typescript/) from [@blorkfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391150/blorkfish)

I downloaded the VS plugin from **typescriptlang.org** and the lastest ExtJS definitions via nuget

> PM> Install-Package extjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

OK, lets start with writing a basic MVC app as described in the blockpost:

> **Compile time type-casting**
>
> The only way to utilize the powerful TypeScript benefits (i.e. type
>   safety) is to manually type-cast these configuration blocks to the
>   correct type by using compile time type casting as follows:
>
> ```
> Ext.application(
>     <Ext_app_Application>{ 
>         // Ext.application config block
>         // now has intellisense and type casting
>     } 
> );
> ```

which ended

[image]

The error says that there is no definition for Ext_app_Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a additional information:

Have you tried `<Ext.app.IApplication>` cause that is valid for the latest version of the ExtJS TypeScript definition. Note that there are differents between the definition used in the blog and the one you get via nuget.

dev comment:

> Cast configuration blocks to the appropriate interface to enable code
>   hinting.

Comment: Where did you get this 'dev' comment from?

Comment: @JJR You can find this [here](https://github.com/brian428/ext-typescript-generator)

Comment: @JJR Oh, you're welcome ;) That was just meant as additional info and not really as answer. But I should not complain about that ;)

Answer (score 2):

The original blog post that I wrote was based on the excellent work done by Mike Aubury (zz9pa), and was published in January 2013.

Around July 2013, brian428 submitted his extjs.d.ts files to DefinitelyTyped.

The differences in these two .d.ts files explains why you are having this error.
Mike's extjs interfaces separated class names using _ (underscore) as follows:

```
interface Ext_AbstractComponent extends Ext_Base { ... }
```

Where brian428's extjs interfaces use . (dot) as follows:

```
interface Ext.AbstractComponent extends Ext.Base { ... }
```

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `Ext.application()` says it accepts an optional argument named `config` of type `any`:

```
Ext.Application(config?: any) : void;
```

So you should just pass in your object like this:

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/extjs/ExtJS.d.ts" />

Ext.application({
    name: 'SampleApp',
    appFolder: '/app/sampleapp',
    controllers: ['SampleController'],
    launch: () => {
        console.log('getting started');
    }
});
```

Comment: So then the writing in the blog is no longer correct? It's about that Ext.define() / Ext.create() accept a object which needs to be cast to the appropriate class, I think to enable intelli sense?

Comment: If intellisense is needed, the ExtJS definition should be updated to add type definitions for the configuration. You could create your own config definition too if you want - but to get things working, just start with this example.

Comment: Ok, I will take your advice. Thank you for this answer and the explanation!

Comment: Using <any> completely defeats the whole point of strongly typing.  I would NOT recommend this approach.

Comment: It depends - it is entirely necessary if you want a dynamic type. If you know the type details, you can of course define it to get auto-completion and type checking.